# Is IPA obsolete?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, ipa

It seems to me that IPA is badly designed and not suitable well for many languages other than English.

Some problems are:

- It uses different characters to denote the same sounds. For example, [ʍ] and [w̥], or [ʃʲ] and [ɕ].
- It does not have characters for even widespread sounds that are used in different languages. For example, the sound, conducted by English "ch" exists in English, Czech, Italian, Russian and many other languages. Yet IPA uses two symbols for it: [tʃ]. The Russian [ч] needs three IPA symbols: [t͡ɕ]
- It uses the same symbols for different sounds. For example the above-mentioned transcription [tʃ] is used both for Belarusian phoneme which is denoted by the letter ч and for the combination of two phonemes [тш]. Similarly, Russian отселить "to resettle away" has [тс] while оцелить "to give aim" has [ц], the both again will be [ts] in IPA.
- It uses different methods to indicate the same features in different sounds. For example, palatal variant of [ɣ] is denoted [ʝ], palatal variant of [tʃ] is denoted [t͡ɕ] while in other cases a superscript [xʲ] is used to indicate palatalization.
- It uses completely different symbols for voiced and voiceless, or palatal and plain variants of the same sound, which does not reflect the sound proximity.

Reading professional literature on comparative linguistics I never encounter use of IPA. The authors usually use ad-hoc transliterations for even languages which have no written form, and transliteration systems of different branches may grossly differ making comparison difficult.

That said I wonder whether IPA really obsolete and whether there is recognized need for a better alphabet which could be used in comparative studies?

Comment: About your second point: "ch" in Italian has a [k] sound, not [tʃ].

Comment: @Alenanno, in Italian с=[tʃ] or [t͡ɕ]

Comment: Not always, for example: ca = [ka], ci = [tʃi]. I don't think we really have [t͡ɕ] in Italian.

Comment: Don't forget that the IPA is an "alphabet", not an "orthography". Just as the Latin alphabet is used very differently for many languages including English and Italian, IPA was also designed to be flexible enough to be used for many languages. There are often multiple "orthographies" for writing *phonemically* the same language, but there will be a lot less (still some) variation in how to write *phonetically*. I don't believe Americanist transcription or any other transcription avoids every one of the issues you list.

Comment: On the second point, surely the reason that English <ch> is transcribed as [tʃ] is because it is a combination of two separate sounds? It's like complaining that IPA uses two symbols to represent English <o> because "toll" is transcribed as [təʊl]. IPA tries to give a single written symbol to every individual sound, regardless of whether multiple sounds may be grouped together in a single symbol in the written language, or indeed of whether a single sound may be written using two characters (e.g. θ and English <th>). Does this make sense, or am I missing something?

Comment: I think that, for the purpose it was designed for -- transcribing the ***sounds*** of human languages, as they are produced by living speakers of the living languages -- IPA is fine. For phonemic purposes, which are almost always the points at issue in comparative linguistics, ad hoc subsets of IPA, augmented by traditional orthographic symbols like č, are common and unremarkable. For other purposes, you are free to design your own; the nice thing about standards, as I'm fond of remarking, is that there are so many to choose from.

Comment: From Professor Wells' blog: "IPA symbols have always had to be interpreted in accordance with conventions implicitly or explicitly defined by the transcriber who uses the symbols. [...] It is convenient (= practical and sensible) for us to use the same phonemic symbol t for the unaspirated dental plosive of French, the aspirated dental plosive of Swedish, the unaspirated alveolar plosive of Czech, and the aspirated alveolar plosive of English." http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2012/09/false-alarm.html

Comment: "So the English consonant at the beginning of red can be written phonemically as r or allophonically ~ impressionistically ~ general-phonetically as ɹ. Both ways of writing it are ‘IPA’; both are equally ‘scientific’; both convey the same information.

The problem is how to convey this point clearly to non-specialists such as my correspondent." (Ibid.)

Comment: Distinguishing between phonetics and phonemics is a good start. Just like learning the multiplication tables is a good start on calculus.

Comment: @Berthilde I do not know for English, but in Russian, Belarusian etc it is surely one sound that transcribed with two symbols in IPA.

Comment: @jlawler so you think IPA is good for phonetics? Do you think using two symbols for common sounds is good? How to distinguish Russian [ц] and [тс] in IPA?

Comment: Surely the IPA system uses that symbol in order to demonstrate that it is an affricate - i.e. a stop, followed by a fricative.

Comment: @Danger Fourpence How to distinguish Russian [ц] and [тс] in IPA? It uses [ts] for both, but the difference in Russian pronounciation is huge, easily distinguishable and changes the meaning. отсенить(to copy) vs. оценить (evaluate), отселить (to resettle away) vs. оцелить (to give aim), отцы (fathers) vs отссы (piss

Comment: I have deleted the off topic comments (the thread was too long). If you need to post more discussions, please use the [Meta] or our [Chat].

Comment: The IPA does let you distinguish between an affricate http://www.langsci.ucl.ac.uk/ipa/symbols.html and a cluster [ts]. You know, there's Google and the IPA Handbook, too - there's even a chapter on Russian there.

Comment: @Alex B. ...joined with a tie bar... So it takes 3 charachters. Is it effective method? Also note that the tie bar usually is NOT used, even in Wikipedia where Russian alphabet is described.

Comment: So what? Or would you rather have a different phonetic notation system for each language? By the way, we usually treat [ts] in English as a cluster and not an affricate because of phonological considerations. As far as articulatory phonetics is concerned, [ts] in English should be an affricate - a stop followed by a homorganic fricative.

Comment: @Alex B. that is my point. IPA is English-centric, it has not characters for some widespread sounds that absent in English. In English ts is indeed a cluster. In Russian there is both such cluster and phoneme and they are distinct. Also IPA has special characters for palatal sounds that exist in English but no special character for other palatal sounds (you have to use j in upper case).

Comment: superscript j is used for palatalized sounds (secondary palatalization), not for palatal sounds. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatal_consonant

Comment: @Alex B. okay, but half of Russian soft consonants are represented with palatals in IPA, the other half - with palatalized mark. I see no consistency in it. For example, Russian ч is represented in IPA as [t͡ɕ] instead of [t͡ʂʲ]. Russian has no hard variant of ч, but Belorussian has.

Comment: @AlexB. Another example is Russian soft consonant [й] which is denoted in IPA as [j] rather than [ɰʲ] - no consistency at all!

Comment: I suggest you re-read a quote from Professor Wells's blog about the IPA that I posted above. It seems you didn't read it carefully enough. *Also, read the IPA Handbook in its entirety.* This should help.

Comment: @Alex B. OK. this ambiguity of notation makes it hardly usable in phonemic comparison of languages IMHO. That's why I never seen it used in comparative linguistics. But the methods currently used are not much better.

Comment: Please clean up the obsolete comments. And if you need to further discuss this, use chat.

Comment: You might be interested in the Shwa script, at www.shwa.org

Comment: Unicode has ʨ as one character for [t͡ɕ] and for ʧ for [tʃ].

Comment: @Christian so one has to measure the distance between the characters to determine whether it is one or two phonemes?

Answer (score 18):

Your criticisms of the IPA seem to be mainly based on patent misapprehensions about how its notation is correctly used.

- In your first impungment of the IPA, you apparently are assuming two different notations of the same sound (in this case, a voiceless labio-velar approximant notated with [ʍ] and  [w̥]) are both unanimously agreed upon transcriptions of one phoneme and are used interchangeably. In reality, they're no more than the result of differences in how the phoneme could be more accurately or most obviously denoted. Whichever notation is employed is more an indication of the preference of whomever it was who employed it rather than the IPA's notational ambiguity. It's a trivial objection to raise, nonetheless.
- To your presumably Anglophone ears, [tʃ] and [t͡ɕ] most likely sound the same. In reality, they correspond to two disparate phonemes. When used by knowledgeable people, [tʃ] invariably denotes the voiceless palato-alveolar affricate, whereas the voiceless alveolo-palatal affricate is signified with [t͡ɕ]. It isn't just a case of one phoneme having different names and transcriptions.
- There's a subtle articulatory distinction to be considered between a palatalized consonant and a palatal consonant which gives the two their different notations. Palatal consonants have a primary articulation with the tongue either toward or in contact with the mouth's hard palate. Some palatal consonants of import are: [ɲ], [c], and [ɟ]. A palatalized consonant (conventionally denoted with a superscript palatal approximant, as in [pʲ] to denote the palatalized voiceless bilabial plosive) are such that they possess a non-palatal primary articulation coupled with a palatal secondary articulation.

  Therefore, the palatalized phoneme [nʲ] is distinguishable from [ɲ]
  because of the latter's palatal primary place of articulation and the
  former's non-palatal primary place of articulation. There's only a
  soupçon of difference between the two, but it's still a difference
  that deserves to be accounted for.
- Different symbols for different phonation isn't a legitimate criticism. Also, there are some phonemes which are given special diacritical marks to individuate their voiced and voiceless counterparts, like with voiceless implosives, for example. This is a complex and nuanced issue and I shan't waste any of my time explaining it here. If you're interested, a Google search will help.

Comment: 1) Indeed this depends on the preference of the author. This is because IPA notation allows use of both symbols. 2) I never claimed that [tʃ] and [t͡ɕ] are the same sound, please re-read. 3) I am aware of such distinction, though IPA uses symbols of palatal or palatized consonants inconsistently for Russian soft consonants. 4)I see, your time is very expensive.

Comment: 1) The IPA only allows for multiple notations fore voice because of complexities involved with precise transcriptions of phonation, which I alluded to. Typically, **only obstruents** have one symbol for voiced and another for voiceless, as with the obstruents [b] and [p]. Cases of voiceless sonorants contrasting with voiced sonorants, voiced implosives, lenis, slack voice, voiced typically voiceless phonemes, etc. are given a ring diacritic. Regrettably, this diacritic could theoretically be given to **any** voiceless sound, leading to an overabundance of confused and disgrunted wiseacres.

Comment: 2) My haste lead me to misconstrue your criticism as having the wrong ill-founded premise. The correct ill-founded premise seems to be that [tʃ] deserves one symbol and not two. On closer inspection, one finds that no affricate could possibly be transcribed with one symbol, because every affricate is necessarily–though not fundamentally–a combination of two separate phonemes. Invariably, [t]+[ʃ]=[tʃ]. In light of this, denoting [tʃ] with less than two phonemes cannot be done without a dramatic loss in precision. And the tiebar in [t͡ɕ] isn't a third symbol. It's used to prevent confusion.

Comment: 3) That's not true. The IPA makes perfectly clear the distinctions in notation and articulation of palatal and palatalized consonants. Widespread ignorance of these distinctions are the cause of these disparate types of phonemes' notations being used interchangeably. People's nescience is no fault of the IPA.

Comment: 1) That is what I mean. You can use different symbol or just add a diacritic. The alphabet is redunant. 2) You're wrong. [t] followed by [ʃ] is not an affricate consonant. As I already pointed out in Russian for instance there is clear destinction between affricate [ц] and sequence [тс]. If one wants to denote the affricate one has to write [t͡s]. That is three Unicode symbols for just one consonant. And that is in "phonetic alphabet", which is supposedly designed for better denoting sounds, not in just some weird real spelling. Highly suboptimal.

Comment: 3) "Widespread ignorance of these distinctions are the cause of these disparate types of phonemes' notations being used interchangeably." - well. This is how it is used in Wikipedia, for example.

Comment: 1) I can only suppose that a phenomenon, wholly accounted for in the IPA, exists to individuate ц from тс. I think that отселить is really [от'селить], with т and с occupying separate syllables, and  оцелить is a monosyllabic word. Another, perhaps more plausible, alternative is that the vowel "е" palatalizes the preceding paired consonants "тс", making it [ts­­J]. Because ц is a single (unpaired) grapheme, the palatalization is not conveyed. Therefore, the differentiation is [tsJ] and [ts]. This hypothesis is simply an extrapolation of a general Slavic grammatical rule I've read in a grammar.

Comment: No, both отселить and оцелить are 3-syllabic words. But you are right that in отселить the phonemes [t] and [s] belong to different syllables. "ц" is always hard in Russian (non-palatal), but it can be soft in Ukrainian, still it is always different from t+s. Example with the both hard: отцапать "shatch, grab" vs отсапать "to work off with a chopper".

Comment: So? 2 characters+diacritic. Is it good way to denote a consonant highly widespread in European languages? IPA is English-centric and the creators even did not account for fellow European languages.

Comment: Sorry. I accidentally deleted the comment you responded to. I concur, actually. The IPA is obviously English-centric. But the assumption that the IPA does not account for other, non-English European languages is counterfactual. Most languages in Europe have the advantage of sharing a close genealogical or geographic propinquity with English, and are therefore readily accounted for within the IPA. Many languages autochthonous to places like Papua New Guinea, sub-Saharan Africa, the Caucacus, Latin America, western Canada, and Southeast Asia are the veritable sufferers of its notation's foibles.

Comment: Languages related to English not necessary have a similar phonology, even German language has nothing in common with English phonologically. Wikipedia's article shows the following IPA sequences used for German consonants: p͡f t͡s t͡ʃ d͡ʒ. Yeah really easy. I am not surprised that no Russian phonologist ever uses IPA (an example of such article http://www.philol.msu.ru/~ruslang/data/pdf/reform.pdf ). I am just curious why it is called "international".

Comment: @Even American linguists often don't use IPA and America is of course the most populous English-speaking country. Last I checked no American dictionary I could find used IPA for pronunciation, but just about all modern dictionaries from the United Kingdom and Australia do. I would assume IPA is mostly used in Europe including Britain.

Comment: @hippietrail I doubt it is used in French, Spanish, Polish or German dictionaries (am I correct?)

Comment: @Anixx: Actually most European languages have phonetic spelling for the majority of their words, at least for native speakers acquainted to the quirks of their languages. I see my wording was a bit ambiguous because I used dictionaries as an example but I only meant that as an indicator of IPA use generally. So while those languages may not use IPA or any other system to indicate pronunciation of native words in monolingual dictionaries, I still assume that in disciplines that require phonetic / phonemic transcriptions will use IPA in those countries...

Comment: @Anixx: That said, sometimes dictionaries for languages with 99% phonetic spelling still have pronunciation guides for the other 1% of words. I used to look in Spanish dictionaries for their entry on the word *jazz* for instance and did find IPA! ... It's also a fun game to try to guess which words are not phonetically spelled in your favourite language (-:

Comment: @hippietrail it could be difficult to guess for Latin alphabet based languages because they usually borrow words without changing the spelling. In Cyrillic-based languages I think one has to expect phonetic spelling nearly always because any borrowed word (either from Latin-based language or another Cyrillic-based one) gets transliterated and re-spelled.

Comment: Yes true, but what about in a Mongolian <-> Russian dictionary? (-; Still this is the problem with discussions based on assumptions rather than objective facts I suppose. I'm in the chat room right now though if you like ...

Comment: @hippietrail with Mongolian-Russian dictionary all the same.

Comment: @Anixx: Your sentence no verb. Though I don't know Mongolian I know that even between Bulgarian and Russian the same letter is used for different sounds, and Mongolian definitely has sounds unfamiliar to Russian speakers. Anyway we are past being warned `Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?`...

Comment: @hippietrail with Mongolian and Bulgarian and even Ukrainian the words get re-spelled as I said.

Comment: I think I missed the part where you said how Mongolian sounds are re-spelled for Russian speakers to understand. IPA is just another way to spell words too. Anyway we're really getting off topic for a comment thread. Please come to the chat room if you wish to continue this conversation: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1336/lgwstks

Comment: Yes, please move to chat (you can use the main one or create a new chat room). When you're done, delete the obsolete comments or flag them for moderator attention, choosing the custom reason. A moderator will act on it and delete the comment thread.

Answer (score 16):

The IPA is useful for what it is: an alphabetic writing system biased towards "major European languages" for performing certain analyses/comparisons/descriptions based essentially on the typographical requirements and linguistic models and theory of 100 years ago. As such:

- it allows you to analyse and denote *certain* phonetic/phonological phenomena that it is often useful to examine, e.g. cross-linguistic categorisation of sounds, comparison of broad features of the sound inventories of languages, description of broad/high-level pronunciation phenomena for the purpose of language description and teaching...;
- it operates more or less as any "alphabet with diacritics" will operate, so you may as well use the alphabet + diacritics that are familiar to many people rather than inventing a new one with essentially similar problems (though there are other similar phonetic transcription systems: the "US" transcription scheme is systemically similar to IPA, but not actually identical in the specifics of which symbols are used where);
- it's become "common currency" in dictionaries and teaching materials in some countries for some languages;
- it is "common currency" for denoting pronunciations in various linguistic journals and in linguistic publications in some countries;
- it is a *tool* to be adapted to specific languages/purposes and extended where necessary-- much of its effectiveness lies in how effectively the linguist is able to apply it to their needs;
- using IPA with modern typography tools (read: "typing IPA on a computer keyboard") is a complete pain in the arse most of the time.

So, it's useful, but not the be-all and end-all of the universe:

- many speech technology applications that require transcriptions don't actually use IPA, but rather some other scheme that is easy to type and more closely adapted to the particular language/analysis needs in question;
- many phonetic and phonological studies nowadays aren't quite so preoccupied with the "armchair segmental analysis" for which IPA is most useful.

So, if IPA isn't useful for what you're doing, nobody's saying you can't use or invent something else that is. On the other hand, if you are in the business of performing the kind of descriptions/analysis that phonetic transcription is useful for and it is for general readership rather than an internal database of an IT application, you may as well use IPA as not: it *is* still "common currency".

Answer (score 0):

The IPA clearly plays an important role: we need to be able to write pronunciation in an unambiguous way.  But maybe we can improve on it.

First of all, IPA looks like a math formula, with all its diacritics, digraphs, and decorations.  That makes it intimidating for learners and limits its value in pedagogy and even in public use (like dictionaries or Wikipedia).

Second, reusing the familiar Roman alphabet was an obvious design choice, but in practice it leads to some confusion.  IPA letters like **c** and **a** are often misread.  John Wells tells a story of including /reply/ in a read-aloud exercise, and having most of the students say "reply" (the **y** is rounded) [Sounds Interesting 3.1, p82].

Among the original design principles of the IPA were to have a letter for each sound, and to avoid diacritics [Handbook of the IPA, p.196].  Now, a century and change later, those principles have been abandoned.  There are a LOT of sounds in the world, and the Roman alphabet simply doesn't have enough letters.  New letters have been created, but they're not in normal fonts or on normal keyboards.  And broad classes of sounds are written with diacritics or digraphs: aspirates, affricates, ejectives, labial-velars, and breathy/murmured sounds.

The vowel model for IPA is an abstract multiplication table of 3 backnesses ×  4 heights × ± rounding [ibid 2.6].  One result is a cluster of hard-to-distinguish sounds in the center.  Very qualified phoneticists can legitimately disagree on a transcription.  Maybe a model based on the acoustics rather then the articulation would have been a better idea.

If we were starting over from scratch, there are some other flaws I'd correct: better symbol names, more consistent use of features, easier letters to write by hand, better integration with tone and intonation.  Some day...